# Will I be able to have relationships with the NPCs, romantic or otherwise?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am just about to jump into the game but I wanna know if I can like have a friend/best friend/ wife or something? and if you can have a wife would she move into your house?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can get [married](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage) and have a [companion](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers).
Marriage involves raising the person's disposition towards you proceeding with a ceremony. Your spouse will move into your house, if you have one, and cook for you.
A companion could be a dog you've rescued, your spouse, or even someone you've paid to follow you around.